# Retrieving a document reference in Flutterflow with a custom dart function by using the collection and a document field

Tags: dart

I am trying to retrieve a document reference from firebase to store in a field of another document.

So I am trying to create a generalized function that allows the retrieval of a document reference when given the collection name, and the value of a "name" field within the document.

Here is what I have, and I'm not sure where to go from here.

the variable 'collection' is a string, and is the name of the collection.
the variable 'name' is a string and is the value of the 'name' field in the document I'm searching  for.

```
import 'dart:math' as math;

DocumentReference? getDocumentReference(
  String name,
  String collection,
) {
var doc = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection(collection)
      .where("name", isEqualTo: name);
return doc.get(); // ??
}
```

So what do I return from this?  I tried using .get(), .data(), etc but they are not working to get me the info I need.

.get() does not return a document reference, and causes an error.  Its returning a 'Future query snapshot'.  and

.data() does not work, the error I get is .data isn't defined for the type Query.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what your problem exactly is, but I interpret it as that .get() gives you a Future<QuerySnapshot<...>>, whereas you need a single document reference.

The problem is that your 'where' query returns a QuerySnapshot, which contains a list of documents. I think you're trying to operate on a single document.

I think another problem is that you are potentially not awaiting the asynchronous Future call.

The steps you need for to achieve what you're doing:

1. do your query
2. await the result
3. get a single document
4. get the reference of the document

a simple way of getting a single document is calling docs[0], but in your full code you probably want to replace this with a better handling of the different cases (exactly 1 doc found, no doc found, more docs found...)

So a template solution using docs[0] is as follows:

```
   void main() async {
        var docref = (await FirebaseFirestore.instance
                        .collection(collection)
                         .where("name", isEqualTo:name)
                         .get()
                      ).docs[0].reference;
  
     }
```